# Creating a round-robin simulation that executes a number of games and ranks the teams in order

Tags: python, loops

I am trying to create a round-robin tournament with 4 teams. Each team will have a random number generated for goals for and goals against between 0 and 5. The task I am struggling with is creating a final standing sorting table that shows the position of the team, its name, the total number of goals for the team (GF), the total number of goals against the team (GA), and the total number of points. Three points are awarded for a win, one for a draw, and none for a
defeat. The final table should look as follows:

```
    The Final Table (sorted):
     Pos Team Name            GF GA PTS
      1 FC Bayern Munich      11 7 6
      2 FC Liverpool           8 7 6
      3 Real Madrid            5 7 3
      4 Orlando SC             6 9 3
```

I am not sure how I can calculate the final scores and organize the table so that it puts the team in the correct rank.

Furthermore, how would this code be done if you want to include a number of teams from an input? Any tips to begin that?

Here is what I have so far. Instead of opting for loops, I decided to go the listing route which is now proving to be difficult. I'm not sure how to assign the GF and GA to the team that has those points and then be able to organize those from least to greatest.:

```
import random

team1 = input("Please enter name of team 1: ")
team2 = input("please enter name of team 2: ")
team3 = input("please enter name of team 3: ")
team4 = input("please enter name of team 4: ")
print()
teams = [team1, team2, team3, team4]


scores = [random.randint(0, 5) for i in range (1,13)]
def schedule():
    print("Tournament Results:")
    print(team1, "vs.", team2,"", scores[0],":",scores[1])
    print(team3, "vs.", team4,"", scores[2],":",scores[3])
    print(team1, "vs.", team3,"", scores[4],":",scores[5])
    print(team2, "vs.", team4,"", scores[6],":",scores[7])
    print(team1, "vs.", team4,"", scores[8],":",scores[9])
    print(team2, "vs.", team3,"", scores[10],":",scores[11])
team1GF = scores[0] + scores[4] + scores[8]
team1GA = scores[1] + scores[5] + scores[9]
team2GF = scores[1] + scores[6] + scores[10]
team2GA = scores[0] + scores[7] + scores[11]
team3GF = scores[2] + scores[5] + scores[11]
team3GA = scores[3] + scores[4] + scores[10]
team4GF = scores[3] + scores[7] + scores[9]
team4GA = scores[2] + scores[6] + scores[8]

schedule()
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused what you're asking, you have the goals for and against for each of the teams, do you want help in calculating scores or sorting scores?

If you want a variable amount of teams then it'd be something like this

```py
team_length = int(input("How many teams do you want to play: "))
teams = []
for i in range(team_length):
    teams.append(input(f"Please enter the name of team {i+1}: "))
```

Though for this you'd also need to change the way you're creating scores to something like this

```py
games_length = team_length * team_length-1
scores = [random.randint(0, 5) for i in range(0, games_length)
```

Comment: For clarification, I don't know how to organize and calculate the scores for each other the teams and have them in a ranking from first to last such as the chart shown first in my description.